# Problem with Vector (\vv{E}) in caption

Tags: captions, vector

I'm enountering an error when using vectors from the package esvect inside a caption.

It's giving me the following errors:

17: Argument of @caption has an extra }. ...t giving errors in a caption: $\vv{E}$ . }

17: Paragraph ended before @caption was complete. ...t giving errors in a caption: $\vv{E}$ . }

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}



\begin{document}
    testing the function of $\vv{E}$
    
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{wave}
        \caption{Working but giving errors in a caption: $\vv{E}$ . }
        \label{fig:wave}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Don't know how to fix this. In theory it's not a real problem as it compiles just fine, but still worrying me a bit.

As both used packages are very common, I don't think this is an unknown incompatibility between these.
All my packages are up to date, I'm using TexStudio 4.6.3 (most recent version).

If anyone has an idea what the issue could be, I'd be happy to hear it.

Greetings Barley

Comment: [`\vv` is fragile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736). As you would also find out, if you would search for the error message, add `\protect` before it.

Comment: "as it compiles just fine": if there is an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output. If there is an error, the document does not compile.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast response. In fact \protect does what needed to be done.